# Configure apache virtual host with angular app

Tags: angular, apache2, config, virtualhost

I ran into a snag where my website's home page will only display the "index of/" page instead of my angular app, or even just an index.html. I'm not sure what's causing this because the vhost config is nearly identical to the three other websites running smoothly on the same server. Apache was restarted and then it quit serving the angular app.

config:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website.com/dist

    <Directory /var/www/html/website.com/dist>
        <Files ~ (\.cgi$)>
            SetHandler cgi-script
            Options ExecCGI
            allow from all
        </Files>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

It's been a while since I initially set this up and with many recent changes trying to get it to work again I main have some silly mess ups I'm overlooking. Any tips or advice is appreciated!

Comment: i have written an article about the same , i hope it will help you , here is the link: http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: @JoelJoseph thanks, your article was quite helpful. Clearing out the default was needed to configure properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was that there was a default v-host file overriding my needed configuration. By deleting the default file, 000-default.conf, the newer file that's needed is loaded into Apache and serves the website without issue.

For others who encounter such an issue double check that there isn't a default or duplicate configuration overriding the one you need to use. See @JoelJoseph's comment for an insightful article and more inforamtion about publishing Angular 6+ apps.